# Synonyms list headers are confusing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms

I'm talking about [the page for tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=renames) provided to us by waffles.

Clarify what "target" and "source" mean if possible --  it confuses me every time I see the list. Maybe put an arrow between the columns:

> **Target     ←     Source        Creator        Renames        Last**

...or maybe change the column names to something clearer, like:

> **Tag        Synonym        Creator        Renames        Last**

Comment: master <- remove?

Comment: Master ← Synonym?