# Allow for tag synonym mappings to be reverted

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

(As an addition to [Fixing the sucktastic merge UI for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142891/fixing-the-sucktastic-merge-ui-for-tags) and [Merging / synonymising should warn of tag wiki loss](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142877/merging-synonimising-tags-should-warn-of-tag-wiki-loss))

Currently, there's no way for a moderator to undo a tag synonym / merge. While a moderator's intent behind making a synonym mapping could be well-intentioned, sometimes what happens is that better arguments get put forward in meta / chat on why the synonym shouldn't exist.

What would be nice to have is for StackExchange to have a way of *undoing* this action. Yes, a mapping can be deleted, but it does not restore tags for merges. If there's a way for the system to maintain a database of tags and allow a grace period window for tags to be un-merged, that would be amazing!

Comment: You can undo a synonym, just not a merge.  If in doubt, don't merge, just synonymize; you still get most of the benefits of the synonym without the merge.